# How can I use xdebug to debug only one virtual host?

Tags: php, apache, profiling, xdebug

I have installed xdebug, I can see in phpinfo() that it's installed (but it's OFF).

However, I don't want to enable it for the whole server/apache2, I just want to enable it for one virtual host.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can set xdebug in `php.ini` with `off` value:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/modules/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable off
xdebug.remote_port 9000
xdebug.idekey PHP-XDEBUG
```

and turn on only `.htaccess` with directive:

```
php_flag   xdebug.remote_enable on
```

Comment: The line `php_value zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/modules/xdebug.so` is incorrect. It should read `php_value zend_extension /usr/lib/php/modules/xdebug.so` which will not work either. You can not load a PHP extension in a `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Only `php_flag xdebug.remote_enable on` in `.htaccess` file.

Comment: This does not disable xdebug completely, just remote debugging. Is there a way to disable it completely for the hosts where it's not needed? Usecase: the mere presence of xdebug makes it impossible to report errors to NewRelic